# How to write simple javascript code for temperature converter..?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to design a simple web page for converting temperature into farenheit or celsius.After entering the value in first textbox andthen after clicking on one of the radio button I should get the result into separate textbox.
Plz help me.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, and explain precisely what problem you are having.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the question is too broad. If you have a specific problem, please edit your post.

Comment: check my answer , let me know if you are facing any difficulties

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="temp" />
<input type="text" id="fh" />

<input type="radio" id="radio"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#radio').change( function() {
   var temp=document.getElementById("temp").value;
    temp=temp-1;
   var fh=temp*1.8+33.8;
document.getElementById("fh").value=fh;
});
```

Note : Done proper validations , Include jquery library

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tvx4s253/)**